# lynx browser, enter hid/pwd as command?

Tags: firewall, nfs, lynx

I am on a network with a firewall that requires a username / password. I want to write a script to do some automated yum installs (specifically, tools to mount an nfs) but first I need to go to a web page in lynx and login to get past firewall. Is there any way I can pass a user / pwd argument to lynx from terminal so it logs in automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way via lynx, but there's a few things you could attempt with **curl** or **elinks**, depending on the configuration of the login page.

If it's just basic proxy authentication, you can try passing the username and password via **curl**:

```
 curl -u username:password http://example.com
```

You can also use **curl** to do more complicated logins, storing session cookies and such. Check out ["Using cURL to automate HTTP jobs"](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html)

Finally, you may be able to do this in a dirty way using [ELinks](http://elinks.or.cz). **ELinks** has a function to save a username and password, and also a command line switch to automatically submit a form. By combining the two, this may be what you need:

Enable password saving in elinks.conf by adding this line:

```
set document.browse.forms.auto_submit = 1
```

Then run the command to automatically submit the first form on a webpage:

```
elinks http://example.com/login -auto-submit 1
```

The problem then is quitting **elinks**, you may have to kill it in your script.

Good luck.